# Schedule Call with send Mail and Log in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to make notification message if some user's 'deleted_at' field is 'null' when daily check?
When occurred that case, I wish to send a email message with that user's name to admin.

```
// app/console/Kernel.php

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $forgotCheckout = DB::table('workings')->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
            foreach($forgotCheckout as $f){
                $user_id = [$f->user_id];
            }
            -- "code" --
        })->daily();
    }
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong... Have a look at the [API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNull): 

`DB::table('workings')->whereNull('deleted_at')->get()`

Comment: Maybe the manual can help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#sending-notifications

Comment: what actually want? As I understand  you need to notify admin about how many users are deleted

Comment: @VasimVanzara just email notify with detected user's name(id) or record(s) to admin. after I will use that information to make CRUD modal.

Comment: @Magnetic: You get proper result in ` $forgotCheckout` variable?

Comment: @Magnetic: What is issue exactly?

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal: do you know how to send email with  $forgotCheckout value to admin?

Comment: This will helpful :  https://appdividend.com/2018/03/01/laravel-cronjob-scheduling-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//app/console/Kernel.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; //for use Mail facade

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $forgot = [];

    $forgotCheckout = Working::whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
    foreach($forgotCheckout as $forgot){
           $forgot;
       }

    if(!is_null($forgot)){
        $schedule->call(function () use($forgotCheckout){
            Mail::send( //send email with valiable $forgot in View file.
                'emails.forgot_checkout',
                compact('forgotCheckout'),
                function ($message) {
                    $message->to('test@email.com');
                    $message->subject('This is test mail');
                }
               );
        })->daily()->when(function() use ($forgotCheckout){ //define how often do this job
            if(!is_null($forgot)){
            \Log::info(Daily check completed.); //write log file                
            return true; // when() will work when return is true.
            }
            else {
            return false; // when() not work because return is false.
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And you can make and modify to use your data with `$forgot` data.

```
// view/emails/forgot_checkout.blade.php

This is test mail for scheduled mail sending...
@foreach($forgotCheckout as $forgot)
  {{$forgot->id}}
  {{$forgot->name}}
@endforeach
```

As most of you know, if you know how to do then it's not difficult:)